# PHP Poker Texas Holdem - Check for straight

Tags: php, poker

I really thought it would be easier to evaluate a straight but alas I am here after a couple days trying.

I have a deck that is dealt, each player gets two cards, when it comes to evaluation I combine the player cards with the community cards and sort them highest to lowest.

The array would look like `['14d', '13d', '12d', '1d', '10d', '9d', '8d'];` eg. Ace Diamonds, King Diamonds, Queen Diamonds, etc..

I've tried multiple methods such as loops and manually evaluating each card, but it needs to be evaluated with a minimum of 5 cards (2 player cards + 3 community cards) up to 7 cards (2 player cards + 5 community cards)

Here is one of my attempts:

```
  $hand =  ['14d', '13d', '12d', '11d', '10d', '9d', '8d']; //Debug hand variable
  $hand_len = count($hand);
  $l_card = (int)$hand[0];

  $set = array();
  rsort($hand, SORT_NUMERIC);
  for ($i=0; $i < $hand_len; $i++) {

    //Which values to compare
    if ( $i+1 != $hand_len && $i+2 != $hand_len) {
      $c1 = (int)$hand[$i]; //14
      $c2 = (int)$hand[$i+1]; //13

      if ( $c1 == $c2+1 ) { //if 14 == 13(+1)
        array_push($set, $hand[$i]);
      }

    } elseif ($i+1 == $hand_len && $i+2 == $hand_len) {
      $c1 = (int)$hand[$i]; //8
      $c2 = (int)$hand[$i-1];//9

      if ( $c1 == $c2-1 ) { //if 8 == 9(-1)
        array_push($set, $hand[$i]);
      }
    }

  }
//Still to add evaluation for 14 (Ace) being used for low straight (eg. 14d, 2d, 3d...).
```

For each card I have to convert to an integer to rid the suit character then do the calculations. I can get some level of success until it has to evaluate the final card in the set.

For example. `['14d', '13d', '12d', '11d', '10d', '9d', '8d'];` <- '8d' would not be evaluated and added to the straight set.

Does anyone have suggestions how to make this operate efficiently and reliably?

Thanks!

Comment: when you say `one of my attempts` does that mean this is the one with the most promise and the one we should study for deficiencies/errors or is that just as example ?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with a "set" is good, but at some point you have to check if you have reached 5 cards. You also have to check if you hit a gap in the straight, where you must start over again. And your code doesn't work for duplicate cards like `12d` and `12h`.

For sake of simplicity I removed the suit from the input and work on numbers only. First you remove any duplicates and sort them like you did with `array_unique()` and `rsort()`. Then you keep a list/set of the cards which are part of the straight. Add new cards to that chain when it fits. This is the case when the last card is only different by the value `1`. When the difference is greater than `1`, then you know it can't be a straight anymore. At that point you have to check for a new straight from *that* location with the remaining cards. See the following example source code:

```
$cards = array(6, 9, 5, 12, 7, 8, 11);
echo "Input cards: ".implode(',', $cards)."\n";
$cards = array_unique($cards);
rsort($cards);

$set = array(array_shift($cards)); // start with the first card
foreach ($cards as $card) {
    $lastCard = $set[count($set)-1];
    if ($lastCard - 1 != $card) {
        // not a chain anymore, "restart" from here
        $set = array($card);
    } else {
        $set[] = $card;
    }
    if (count($set) == 5) {
        break;
    }
}
if (count($set) == 5) {
    echo "Found a straight with ".implode(',', $set)."\n";
} else {
    echo "No straight\n";
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Input cards: 6,9,5,12,7,8,11
Found a straight with 9,8,7,6,5
```

The loop iterates as follow over the sorted cards `12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5`:

```
sorted cards               set content
--------------------------------------
12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5      [12]  <-- start set
     ^                     [12, 11]
        ^                  [9]   <-- break, restart set from here
           ^               [9,8]
              ^            [9,8,7]
                 ^         [9,8,7,6] 
                    ^      [9,8,7,6,5]
```